# Ant target with property part of the name attribute

Tags: ant

I want to define a target using a property as part of its name attribute, but the property doesn't seem to resolve.

```
<property name="foo" value="FOO" />

<target name="${foo}.init.win32" />

<antcall target="${foo}.init.win32" />
```

The error I get is: Target "FOO.init.win32.x86" does not exist in the project.

I guess Ant doesn't allow this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ant doesn't allow variable name of the target. Otherwise dependency calculation can be very difficult task

Comment: thanks - I just re-worked it to where I wouldn't need the variable in the target Name attribute. It resulted in more fluff, but... oh well.